# Instream and Stream

Tags: java, java-stream

Whats the difference between the two? Are they the same thing ?

In Stream API

**Filter**

`Stream<T> filter(Predicate<? super T> predicate)`

Returns a stream consisting of the elements of this stream that match the given predicate.

This is an intermediate operation.

**mapToInt**

`IntStream mapToInt(ToIntFunction<? super T> mapper)`

Returns an `IntStream` consisting of the results of applying the given function to the elements of this stream.

This is an intermediate operation.

`Filter` returns a `stream` and `mapToInt` returns an `IntStream`.

Comment: did you read the javadoc of IntStream?

Answer (score 3):

`IntStream` -> `Stream` of only `int`

`Stream`   -> `Stream` of `Objects` (any objects including `Integer`, `Double`, `Long`, `String`, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

*Are they the same thing ?*
Both are extending`BaseStream`. Thus they have a common interface. But the methods `filter` and `mapToInt` don't belong to this interface.

*Whats the difference between the two?*
`Stream<T>` is a `Stream` of `T` where `T` is a generic type parameter of `Stream`. Since a generic type parameter cannot have a primitive type as type argument there is no way to declare a `Stream<int>`. To have a stream of primitive integers a dedicated type `IntStream` has been defined.

If you have a `Stream<Integer>` and want to use the methods the type `IntStream` offers (i.e. `min()`, `toArray()`) you need first to convert the `Integer` elements to `int` elements. This is the task of the method `mapToInt` which applied on a `Stream<T>` will return an `IntStream`. To convert the elements to `int` this method takes a `Function` which does the actual mapping/conversion.

For example:

```
    int[] arrayOfPositiveInts = Stream.of(0, 1, 2, 3, 4)
            .filter(i -> i > 0)
            .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
            .toArray();
```

This shows the `filter` method which is applied on `Stream<Integer>` but uses [unboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) to compare the `Integer` elements with `int` `0`. The method `mapToInt` uses the method `Integer.intValue()` to explicitly return for an `Integer` the corresponding `int` value.

Because of unboxing you could also use:

```
.mapToInt(i -> i)
```

But `Function.identity()` whose implementation does the same will not work:

<del>`.mapToInt(Function.identity()`</del>

because it ([JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html#identity())):

> always returns its input argument.

The type of the `Stream` is `Integer` whereas `mapToInt` expects an `int`.

Summarizing:
The difference between `Stream` and `IntStream` (according to the title of this question) is the type of the streamed elements. `Stream` handles arbitrary [reference types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3). `IntStream` is a dedicated type dealing with elements of [primitive](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2) `int` type. And of course both types offer different methods.